# Convert string to integer recursively?

Tags: c, recursion

Here is a simple function that converts a string to an integer.

```
int str2int(char *str)
{
    int ret = 0;
    char *c;

    for (c = str; (*c != '\0') && isdigit(*c); ++c)
        ret = ret*10 + *c - '0';

    return ret;
}
```

As an exercise, I'd like to write a recursive function that does the same thing. This is what I came up with.

```
int str2int2(char *c, int *i)
{
    if (*c == '\0' || !isdigit(*c))
        return *i;

    *i = *i * 10 + *c - '0';

    return str2int2(c + 1, i);
}

.
.
int i = 0;
.
... str2int2(str, &i);
```

Is there a way to write the recursive function without using the extra `int*` argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it's easy enough, but you need to write two functions, one with an accumulator, like this:

```
int str2int_rec(char *c, int accum)
{
    if (!c || !*c || !isdigit(*c))
        return accum;

    return str2int_rec(c + 1, accum * 10 + (*c - '0'));
}

int str2int(char *c)
{
    return str2int_rec(c, 0);
}
```

Comment: Not strictly necessary, but certainly a lot cleaner. This is the practical answer that you should use, compared to my answer that's just ridiculous. +1

Comment: Also note that the str2int_rec function is tail-recursive, which means that the compiler can potentially reduce it to a loop just like the original imperative code.

Comment: +1 I completely botched up the accumulator part of my str2int2() function.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could hide the functionality from the person using the function. So you will have a function named `int str2int(char *str)` which will call `int str2int(char *c, int *i)` thereafter.

It's how I've done it in the past.

Comment: You should show how to do this instead of just outlining the problem. It's rather trickier than you might think from your succinct "answer".

Comment: I'm sorry, I would have thought it was quite simple as all it is, is calling the method from a new method, as illustrated above accepted answer. I find that my so-called "answer" was not very far off from the answer, bar the actual example code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may use [horner scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner_scheme) in order not to keep any 'i'.

You must reverse the string (yeah quit ugly) and then you can simply use:

```
int str2int (char* str)
{
    if (*str+1)
    {
        return 10*str2int(str+1)+(*str-'0');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean "reverse" rather than "revert"

Comment: yep, corrected. Thanks :) (english is not my native language)

Comment: One problem here is that when you reverse the string you'd have to keep the null byte at the end. Might not be impossible, but certainly a pain in the ass.

Comment: @Chris: there might be problems but I thought he wanted an elegant solution rather than a "working" one.

Answer (score 0):

One way could involve passing the length of the digit as an argument so we can read backwards efficiently:

```
int strtoi(char *c, size_t l)
{
    return l ? c[l-1] - '0' + 10 * strtoi(c, l - 1) : 0;
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
int i = strtoi("432", 3);
```

Or:

```
char *c = "432";
int i = strtoi(c, strlen(c));
```

But it's not always optimal to bother with the length of a string. Plus, if a string has characters after a number, we'd have to factor that in manually, because this function won't do it for us. We can't (shouldn't) use `strlen()` inside our function to avoid having to pass arguments, because that can cause a considerable slowdown to recalculate the string's length every time. Surely there must be a way to do this from the beginning, even if we have to bring out the heavy artillery:

```
int strtoi(char *c)
{
    if(!isdigit(*c)) return 0;
    int i = strtoi(c + 1);
    return i + pow(10, (int)(log(i + 1)/log(10)) + (i != 0)) * (*c - '0');
}
```

And no, that `(int)` cast isn't optional. Basically, all of that math calculates the power of 10 we need to multiply our current digit by, based on the number returned by the last recursive call.

I understand this is probably a learning exercise, but recursion is not the be-all, end-all of programming. In some languages, and for some tasks, it is what some, myself included, would call beautiful, but from the looks of it this is not one of those cases.

Comment: Except that the pow function might be expensive (while (power--) result *= result;) ...

Comment: Power might be expensive, but I sure as hell trust compiler and library writers more than a simple loop. Besides, `log()` might also be expensive (perhaps more so), and we call it twice (but any sane compiler will optimize the second one away). Shall we resort to bit-level hacks to optimize this prematurely, or trust that the OP is going to be using the iterative (or Barry Kelly's) solution anyway?